# Add a query parameter when a page gets bookmarked

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, google-chrome, bookmarklet

Is it possible to add a query parameter to a page when it gets bookmarked via Chrome?
So that when you add a bookmark at https://www.example.com, it gets bookmarked as https://www.example.com/?bookmarked?

I think I need to add JavaScript or a browser script to detect if the page is about to get bookmarked. I've tried with the `window` object but it has only the `window.history` which I don't need.

Comment: There is no event or anything like that you could listen for, this happens outside of the context of your page. At most you could manipulate the URL, if you put your own “add bookmark” functionality inside the page itself, and then get the user to use that, instead of their browser’s default mechanism. (Talking about stuff like https://gist.github.com/oilvier/70abd45d1f2ffc98b568, or other version you can go research yourself; how much that is still functional in current browsers, I don’t know, you’d have to check.)

Answer (score 0):

You can not detect bookmark events in browser, if you wish, you can handle that somehow creating your Chrome Extension (that could be written in js). There you can get permissions to bookmarks, and access them through 'chrome.bookmarks'. And then you can update URL using 'chrome.tabs.update'

More info about [bookmarks](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks) and [tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs).